# problems with using Switch inside my function

Tags: powershell

I made a function for learning PowerShell it is.
https://github.com/dcazman/MRNAP
If anyone wants to see it entirely.

When I first made the function it was all If statements. I then learned I could use switches inside the code and it might be better.  Also for learning.

I changed the code and added two switches in it but now it does not work correctly.

My question is I thought when someone used -UTC the switch would be used but it seems to me that if the switch is there or not I get different results 'randomly'. Here is a snip of the code.

```
Switch ($UTC) {
            { $JustDate -and !$NoSeperators } { $FullPath = Join-AnyPath $DirectoryName ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy_MM_dd-") + ($ReportNameExt)); break }
            { $NoSeconds -and !$NoSeperators } { $FullPath = Join-AnyPath $DirectoryName ((get-date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy_MM_ddThhmm-") + ($ReportNameExt)); break }
            { !$NoSeperators } { $FullPath = Join-AnyPath $DirectoryName ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy_MM_ddThhmmss-") + ($ReportNameExt)); break }

            # Remove dash and underscores with NoSeperators switch.
            { $JustDate -and $NoSeperators } { $FullPath = Join-AnyPath $DirectoryName ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ($ReportNameExt)); break }
            { $NoSeconds -and $NoSeperators } { $FullPath = Join-AnyPath $DirectoryName ((get-date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddThhmm") + ($ReportNameExt)); break }
            { $NoSeperators } { $FullPath = Join-AnyPath $DirectoryName ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddThhmmss") + ($ReportNameExt)); break }
        }
```

My $fullpath gets populated incorrectly
MRNAP -UTC does not create a filename with universal time always. The code randomly goes into one of my two switches.

What am I not understanding?
Do I go back to If statements?

Comment: Correct, the switch is going to execute whether the value of `$UTC` is `$true` or `$false` - the only difference is going to be the value of `$_` inside the `switch` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `switch` statement is *not* a 1-to-1 replacement for an `if`-statement!

A `switch` statement, in PowerShell at least, is a simplified *loop* statement. Your current `switch` statement could be re-written as:

```
foreach($_ in $UTC){
  if($JustDate -and !$NoSeperators){
    $FullPath = Join-AnyPath $DirectoryName ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy_MM_dd-") + ($ReportNameExt))
  }
  if($NoSeconds -and !$NoSeperators){
    $FullPath = Join-AnyPath $DirectoryName ((get-date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy_MM_ddThhmm-") + ($ReportNameExt))
  }
  if(!$NoSeperators){
    $FullPath = Join-AnyPath $DirectoryName ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy_MM_ddThhmmss-") + ($ReportNameExt))
  }
  if($JustDate -and $NoSeperators){
    $FullPath = Join-AnyPath $DirectoryName ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ($ReportNameExt))
  }
  if($NoSeconds -and $NoSeperators){
    $FullPath = Join-AnyPath $DirectoryName ((get-date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddThhmm") + ($ReportNameExt))
  }
  if($NoSeperators){
    $FullPath = Join-AnyPath $DirectoryName ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddThhmmss") + ($ReportNameExt))
  }
}
```

Re-reading it as a `foreach` loop, you can maybe see that the *value* of `$UTC` makes *no difference whatsoever*!

I hope this explains :)

Comment: I think we are saying I should move back to if statements? my understanding of switch was wrong.

Comment: @dcaz I'm just trying to explain how `switch` works when you use scriptblock clauses :) your question doesn't contain enough details for me to say you should be going back to anything, but I _suspect_ you can simplify your code significantly by re-designing your parameters

Comment: Fair enough @marhias